# Select most recent distinct pairs by timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns:

- id (autoincrement)
- created_at
- topic_id
- code_id
- value

The table has many rows with the same (topic_id, code_id).

For a given list of topic ids and code ids, I'd like to select the latest rows(= with greatest created_at) with unique (topic_id, code_id) combinations.

I tried:

```
select distinct topic_id, code_id from topic_values where topic_id in (...) and code_id in (...) order by created_at desc;
```

This is wrong because:

- It only selects topic_id and code_id
- It orders by latest created_at globally (the ordering by latest created_at should be within the scope of (topic_id, code_id).

I then tried:

```
select * from topic_values where topic_id in (...) and code_id in (...) group by topic_id, code_id order by created_at desc;
```

This is wrong because:

- It orders by latest created_at globally (the ordering by latest created_at should be within the scope of (topic_id, code_id).

How could I achieve this? Ideally, I'd love the query to utilize the following indices I have on the table:

```
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`,`topic_id`,`code_id),
  KEY `created_at_2` (`created_at`,`code_id`,`topic_id`),
  KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`,`code_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `topic_id_2` (`topic_id`,`created_at`,`code_id`),
  KEY `code_id` (`code_id`,`topic_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `code_id_2` (`code_id`,`created_at`,`topic_id`),
```

Comment: Do you mean single records for each unique (topic_id, code_id) with latest created_at ? Please share some sample data with output expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use window function to find first row for each group order by date in descending order

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by topic_id, code_id order by created_at desc) rn
  from topic_values
  where topic_id in (1,2,3) and code_id in (4,5,6)
) r where rn = 1
order by id
```

or subquery with max date for each group

```
select a.*
from topic_values a
join (
  select topic_id, code_id, max(created_at) max_date
  from topic_values
  where topic_id in (1,2,3) and code_id in (4,5,6)
  group by topic_id, code_id
) r on a.topic_id = r.topic_id and a.code_id = r.code_id and a.created_at = r.max_date
where
 a.topic_id in (1,2,3) and a.code_id in (4,5,6)
order by id
```

second option will get multiple rows if it happens multiple rows with same max created_at for same topic_id and code_id. If it is desired, it can replace `row_number()` in first option with `rank()`

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4d26dffc115c9610c6e21a55d149676